# Android JSON access thumbnail element

Tags: java, android, json

I have this json result http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=25&q=http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/51120/rss.xml

I am trying to access the thumbnails for each news article located in entries>mediaGroups>contents>thumbnails>url

However I am unsure of how to access that deep in the element. This is my code so far.

```
public List<NewsObj> constructJSON(String jsonIN){
    ArrayList<NewsObj> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        //add more levels to extract json
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonIN);
        String responseData = jsonObject1.getString("responseData");
        Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL1",responseData);

        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(responseData);
        String feed = jsonObject2.getString("feed");
        Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL2",feed);

        JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject(feed);
        String entries = jsonObject3.getString("entries");
        Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL3", entries);

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(entries);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray1.length();i++){
            JSONObject mediaGroups = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
            String mediaItems = mediaGroups.getString("mediaGroups");
            String title = mediaGroups.getString("title");
            String url = mediaGroups.getString("link");
            String description = mediaGroups.getString("contentSnippet");
            String publishedDate = mediaGroups.getString("publishedDate");
//                main information for news article

            //for further thumbnail sizes?
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(mediaItems);
            for(int j=0;j<jsonArray2.length();j++){
                JSONObject contents = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
                String contentItems = contents.getString("contents");
                Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTARRAY2",contentItems);

                JSONArray jsonArray3 = new JSONArray(contentItems);
                for(int k=0;k<jsonArray3.length();k++){
                    JSONObject items = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(k);
                    //too specific
                    String imgurl = items.getString("url");
                    //Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTARRAY3",imgurl);
                    NewsObj aObj = new NewsObj(title, imgurl,url, publishedDate);
                    newsList.add(aObj);
                }
            }
        }

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("RECEIVEJSONERROR",e.toString());
    }
    return newsList;
}
```

Comment: You're going to keep getting links on how to parse JSON if you keep asking the same question :) If you'd like a simpler solution, consider using Gson (and Retrofit, if you'd like). And use this site to create some Java classes http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: Thanks, would Gson or retrofit be much simpler?

Comment: Retrofit turns REST APIs into basically Java methods (it has a somewhat high learning curve), and Gson is used to deserialize a JSON string into a Java object without needing to manually traverse and parse yourself. That sounds simpler to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make another **JSONArray** for **thumbnails**. For Reference [See Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Try This

```
public List<NewsObj> constructJSON(String jsonIN){
ArrayList<NewsObj> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    //add more levels to extract json
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonIN);
    String responseData = jsonObject1.getString("responseData");
    Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL1",responseData);

    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(responseData);
    String feed = jsonObject2.getString("feed");
    Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL2",feed);

    JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject(feed);
    String entries = jsonObject3.getString("entries");
    Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTLEVEL3", entries);

    JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(entries);
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray1.length();i++){
        JSONObject mediaGroups = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
        String mediaItems = mediaGroups.getString("mediaGroups");
        String title = mediaGroups.getString("title");
        String url = mediaGroups.getString("link");
        String description = mediaGroups.getString("contentSnippet");
        String publishedDate = mediaGroups.getString("publishedDate");
       //                main information for news article

        //for further thumbnail sizes?
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(mediaItems);
        for(int j=0;j<jsonArray2.length();j++){
            JSONObject contents = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
            String contentItems = contents.getString("contents");
            Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTARRAY2",contentItems);

            JSONArray jsonArray3 = new JSONArray(contentItems);
            for(int k=0;k<jsonArray3.length();k++){
                JSONObject items = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(k);
                //too specific
                String imgurl = items.getString("url");
                //Log.d("RECEIVEJSONOBJECTARRAY3",imgurl);

                String thumbnails = items.getString("thumbnails");

                JSONArray jsonArray4 = new JSONArray(thumbnails);
                for(int l=0;l<jsonArray4.length();l++){
                JSONObject thumbnails1 = jsonArray4.getJSONObject(l);

                String height = items.getString("height");
                String width = items.getString("width");
                String thumburl = items.getString("url");

                }
                NewsObj aObj = new NewsObj(title, imgurl,url, publishedDate);
                newsList.add(aObj);
            }
        }
    }

}catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("RECEIVEJSONERROR",e.toString());
}
return newsList;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much. It works but I get 5 results per thumbnail with different resolutions, how do I get one of them only?

Comment: yes because its array so you have 5 values so now if you just want 1 value then you need to put condition there to get only one value,.

Comment: I seen there all 5 results are same for Key `contents` so you need to manage those from web service i think

Comment: I can't though. Could I select every 1st option?

Comment: Yes sure !! why not

Comment: Put condition there for `contentItems` (jsonArray3)   if(k==0){ //do stuff}

Comment: Could you put your answer in ? Im a little confused

Comment: Oops I just leave from office now I will update it whenever I get time

Comment: Oh i got it! Thats okay! Thank you so much

Comment: Hello you got solution or not ?

Comment: Yup Thank you so much